# How to treat sass as css modules in ts project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I would like to make a React web application with SSR + SPA (Isomorphic Web App). Now this project uses express servers and React + React router etc but I am worried about how to operate styles.

https://github.com/konojunya/isomorphic-web-react

In the typescript project, the server side builds using the tsc command, and the client uses webpack v4.

I want to import sass into a component and treat it as css modules, but I wrote `import * as styles from" path / index.scss "` in the compport by writing the loader setting to webpack. There is an error because it is typescript. We solved it by creating `scss.d.ts` in typings. When building, there was no css in the folder after the build. How do I set it? Please tell me if you have a good sample etc.

Comment: You need something like `sass-node` to compile scss to css